# Rectangle Enclosure (Python3)

Tags: python

I am trying to create a solution to this problem, with my code focusing on looping(for and while):

> Let parameter Q be a list of "rectangles", specified by width, height,
>   and (x,y)-location of the lower left corner. Enclosure(Q) returns the
>   smallest rectangle that contains each rectangle in Q . The way a
>   rectangle is represented is by tuple, (x,y,width,height).

Here is my code so far:

```
def Enclosure(Q):
    c = []
    d = []
    for (x,y,width,height) in sorted(Q):
        c.append(x)
        d.append(y)
    print(c)
    print(min(c))
    e=tuple([min(c)]+[min(d)])
    print(e)
```

Ignore the print statements, those are only there for debugging purposes. My code to this point creates a tuple of the (x,y) coordinates of the lower left corner of the enclosing rectangle that I am trying to have the program form. But after this point, I have absolutely no idea on how to find the (height,width) of the enclosing rectangle. How can I do that?

Also, here is an example of the program should do when it runs:

```
R1 = (10,20,5,100) #R1,R2,R3 are each rectangles
R2 = (15,5,30,150) #layout of the tuple:(x,y,width,height)
R3 = (-4,30,20,17)
Enclosure([R1,R2,R3])
(-4, 5, 49, 150) #rectangle that encloses R1,R2,R3
```

Comment: What enclosing triangle? You mean the enclosing rectangle?

Comment: You could create the smallest enclosing triangle too.  Bonus points!

Comment: " after this point, I have absolutely no idea on how to find the (height,width) of the enclosing rectangle" ... how would you do it on paper?  And how did you do it for `(-4, 5, 49, 150)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def Enclosure(Q):
    c = []
    d = []
    x2 = []
    y2 = []
    for (x,y,width,height) in sorted(Q):
        c.append(x)
        d.append(y)
        x2.append(width + x)
        y2.append(height + y)
    e = tuple([min(c)]+[min(d)] + [max(x2) - min(c)] + [max(y2) - min(d)])
    print(e)
```

You could replace `e = tuple...` to:

```
e=(min(c), min(d), max(x2) - min(c), max(y2) - min(d)) # This makes a tuple directly
```

to avoid making first a list, and converting it to tuple as you did.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you can explain why you used inheritance or your teacher will know you are cheating:

```
class Geometry(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


class Point(Geometry):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Point at {s.x},{s.y}>".format(s=self)


class Rectangle(Geometry):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super(Rectangle, self).__init__(x, y)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    @property
    def oposite_corner(self):
        return Point(self.x + self.width, self.y + self.height)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Rectange of {s.width}x{s.height} at {s.x},{s.y}>".format(s=self)


def enclosing_rectangle(rect_list):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = (
        min([r.x for r in rect_list]),
        min([r.y for r in rect_list]),
        max([r.oposite_corner.x for r in rect_list]),
        max([r.oposite_corner.y for r in rect_list]),
    )
    return Rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
```

Please test and fix any bug by yourself (hint: `super` changed):

```
>>> l = [Rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4), Rectangle(-1, -1, 1, 1), Rectangle(3, 4, 1, 1)]
>>> enclosing_rectangle(l)
<Rectangle of 5x7 at -1,-1>
```

[update]

What?!? A delete vote? Care to explain what is so offensive with this answer?

Comment: `... on ...` is not a valid python syntax.

Comment: "Make sure you can explain why you used inheritance". There is no reason to create this deep hierarchy. This is bad practice. If you were going to use inheritance, it would make more sense to inherit from a `namedtuple`.

Comment: @Marcin: I would not call 2 layers a "deep" hierarchy... It makes sense to have a base class because geometric entities are like to have many properties in common. Cut me some slack here, clearly it is an assignment and I was trying to make the OP study a little, not show off the epitome of efficiency.

Comment: @PauloScardine There's only one kind of geometric entity here.

Comment: @Marcin: There are two, Point and Rectangle. Creating a Point entity makes the interface prettier: you can use `rectangle.oposite_corner.x` instead of `rectangle.oposite_conrner[0]`. But I understand your point, there is a minimalist solution using plain tuples. Fine! If you think this minimalist solution is more didactic, then we agree to disagree.

Comment: @PauloScardine Having both `Geometry` and `Point` doesn't buy you anything. I'm not advocating eliminating classes. I'm saying that you use classes badly, probably because you were told by C++ or Java users that creating lots of unnecessary classes was the Right Thing. There are good reasons why in those languages they need to provision for things they may never need, but it's just not necessary in python, or any reasonable dynamic, object-oriented language.

Comment: @Marcin: I don't write class hierarchies for the sake of it, I write them for DRY. In my experience geometric constructs share enough properties and methods that a base class is worth. But again, it is a free world and you have your right to troll around.